# Sending an email using nodemailer not working on remote but working in local host

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

Hello I am using nodemailer to send an email. It works fine on local host but it doesn't work when I deploy it to the remote website.

I get the following error message when I try to send an email on the remote website:

```
ERROR ===  { Error: Invalid sender “<Myemailaddress@gmail.com>”
2016-08-15T05:05:01.034175+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SMTPConnection._formatError (/app/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:493:15)
2016-08-15T05:05:01.034175+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SMTPConnection._setEnvelope (/app/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:688:30)
2016-08-15T05:05:01.034176+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SMTPConnection.send (/app/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:364:10)
2016-08-15T05:05:01.034177+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SMTPTransport.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/lib/smtp-transport.js:126:24)
2016-08-15T05:05:01.034178+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/lib/smtp-transport.js:162:21
2016-08-15T05:05:01.034178+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/app/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:1185:5)
2016-08-15T05:05:01.034179+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:307:22)
2016-08-15T05:05:01.034180+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/app/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:634:16)
2016-08-15T05:05:01.034180+00:00 app[web.1]:     at SMTPConnection._onData (/app/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:458:10)



var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Mailgun',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.MAILGUN_USERNAME,
    pass: process.env.MAILGUN_PASSWORD
  }
});

/**
 * 
 */
exports.contact = function(from, to) {

  var mailOptions = {
    from: from.name + ' ' + '<'+ from.email + '>',
    to: to.email,
    subject: from.subject || "No Subject",
    text: from.message
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
    if (err){
      console.log("ERROR === ", err);
    }
  });
};
```

I have already given access for my email address for less secure apps so that should not be the problem. Does anyone know why it would work on the local website but not the remote website?

Comment: Some security check my restrict your SMTP server to send emails if the domain  of senders email does not match the domain of registered email.

Comment: Currently I'm using Mailgun and I am just testing it out with the sandbox domain name which should work locally and remotely. I only have 2 authorized users which is the sender and receiver.

Comment: then why the sender email ID contains gmail.com  i.e Myemailaddress@gmail.com

Comment: There are 2 email addresses, one comcast and one gmail. On Mailgun, sandbox domains are restricted to authorized recipients. In this case, the comcast and gmail account are both authorized recipients and thus eligible to send and receive emails.

Comment: ok, no more comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Nodemailer does not support proxies and currently there is no plan to add any support for these, sorry.
```

Reference - [Nodemailer Issue With Proxy](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/125)

Answer (score 0):

Alright it appears that adding the brackets seemed to prevent nodemailer from working on remote even though it worked locally.

I changed the code to the following:

```
  var mailOptions = {
    from: from.email
    to: to.email,
    subject: from.subject || "No Subject",
    text: from.message
  };
```

And it works now for sending emails on my remote server

Answer (score 0):

Disable Captcha temporarily from [here](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha)